# How do I block most emails from being sent to a specific email address (unless they're on a whitelist)

Tags: linux, centos, email, smtp, sendmail

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

I want to block most emails going to a specific sendmail mailbox unless they are on an approved "whitelist".  Is this possible to do in sendmail?

Answer (score 2):

@quanta should have qualified that answer - it is possible. Sendmail is a very powerful heuristic rules processing engine which can be configured to do all sorts of things. It's just rather hard to do what you ask (would probably require re-writing of the sendmail.cf file rather than sendmail.mc) and easier to implement it in other ways.

Obvious solutions include using [a milter](https://www.milter.org/milters) like [mailfromd](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/mailfromd/manual/mailfromd.html) or use procmail (with an [approporaite recipe](http://impressive.net/people/gerald/2000/12/spam-filtering.html)) as the delivery agent.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write a version of check_compat rule set, but take care if you are using FEATURE(compat_check). IMHO the easiest way to achieve this is to use MIMEDefang and implement the whitelist in your own version of the filter_recipient subroutine within mimedefang-filter.